# Can I replace a ceiling fan capacitor having resistors with one having no resistors?

Tags: ceiling, fans, capacitor

My old ceiling fan shows (3 wire) two capacitors:  one leg is 1.5 uFD with a 270k ohm resistor, the other leg is 3uFD with a 270k ohm resistor, .5 watt, the voltage is 300v.

I can find a replacement 3 wire capacitor with one leg 1.5 uFD, one leg 3uFD, **but no resistors are shown.**  The voltage is 250v.  Is the replacement safe to use?  Or do I need o add a 270k ohm .5 watt resistor to each leg of the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the resistors to your new capacitors to keep it design safe. You can use the old resistors if they can be separated from the capacitor. In old fans, the resistors were used to bleed off the voltage after being removed from the circuit. Newer fans had other means to accomplish this.

Comment: Thank you Jack, I'll add the resistors.